# How can I package up a PowerShell script so it runs when I click on shortcut?

Tags: powershell

I have a sample .ps PowerShell script that was created for me.

Can someone tell me how I can make it so this shell runs in the background when I click on a windows shortcut icon.

Comment: Try this google search "How can I package up a PowerShell script so it runs when I click on shortcut?" - https://www.google.com/search?q=How+can+I+package+up+a+PowerShell+script+so+it+runs+when+I+click+on+shortcut%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a shortcut to

powershell -noexit -executionpolicy bypass -File script.ps

Comment: can you explain what -noexit does.  Actually I want the script to run from start to finish and not to be visible in a command window. Is that possible ?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx

-NoExit
Does not exit after running startup commands.

you should experiment a bit and test whether starting your script with or without noexit suits your needs